# Flex-centered content of boxes are not working anymore

Tags: html, css

I have several boxes wit images and text containing and I want that content to be correctly aligned even if the images have slightly different dimensions. I already have that, so it looks (and shall look) like that 
[image: this is the way it shall look]

but then I had to enter a a-tag at one of the wrappers of the boxes and the whole thing crashed so it looked like that
[image: And this is how it shall not look but now does]

The whole thing can be seen at https://codepen.io/daiaiai/pen/MWgoqdB

So what it is basically set up like is so:

```
<div class="row wrapthat category_marks">
<div class="col col-6er">
<a href="#">
  <div class="marken_box">
    <div class="marken_icons">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/hzhXhf3X/Abarth.png">
      <p><strong>Abarth</strong><br>Erfahren Sie mehr über Ihre Vorteile.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a> 
</div>       <!--- And all the other boxes ...following that structure -->
   </div>
```

And the css looks pretty much like so

```
body{
  background:red;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin:100px auto;

}.category_marks {
    -ms-flex-pack: center!important;
    justify-content: center!important;
}
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.col-6er {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 16.66666666666667%;
    flex: 0 0 16.66666666666667%;
    max-width: 16.66666666666667%;
}
.col {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.marken_box {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 87px -35px rgba(85,95,85,0.6);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 255px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
div.marken_icons {
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 110px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
img.marken_icons, .marken_icons img {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 10%;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 20%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: auto 20%;
}
.category_marks a p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: rgb(87,87,87);
      font-size: calc(14px * 1.2);
}
```

What did I do wrong there and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-wrap` property to properly wrap the divs into position.

As for the alignment of images, I have simply aligned them on flex-end using `align-items` property. 
Also define `display:flex` on anchor tag to makes all the card of same height. Let me know if this works

```
body{
  background:red;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin:100px auto;

}.category_marks {
    -ms-flex-pack: center!important;
    justify-content: center!important;
}
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.col-6er {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 16.66666666666667%;
    flex: 0 0 16.66666666666667%;
    max-width: 16.66666666666667%;
}
.col {
    margin: 5px;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.marken_box {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 87px -35px rgba(85,95,85,0.6);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 255px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
div.marken_icons {
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 110px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;  
}
img.marken_icons, .marken_icons img {
    //width: 60%;
    margin: 0 10%;
    //width: 60%;
    margin: 0 20%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: auto 20%;    
}
.category_marks a p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: rgb(87,87,87);
    font-size: calc(14px * 1.2);  
}
a {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the items are not wrapping. Try adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to the parent wrapping elements (the ones with the `display: flex` attribute):

```css
div.marken_icons {
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 110px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

**Edit**: To elaborate, when you use the `display: flex` attribute, the browser will try to display all direct child elements on the same row unless you specify otherwise by explicitly stating you want the content to wrap.

What may have 'changed' the behaviour is that you may have had a wrapping div between the current children and the parent, which has since been removed.

Comment: Thanks! That already made it less the disaster :) But now the heigh attribute of the image t is still ignored and things aren't aligned at all. Could you have a look here: https://codepen.io/daiaiai/pen/MWgoqdB

Comment: Image sizes will be a different issue unfortunately, but it might be worth trying setting images to all have a fixed height and using `object-fit: contain` to resize the image accordingly - [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)